# Iphone 3g Sample Application

Tags: iphone, 3g

I'm an android developer.. My brother has received one old iphone 3g and I want to create a sample application for this device.
I have an imac 21" with OSX 10.5.1... What i need to make an application from my mac? thanks boys!

Answer (score 2):

To develop iPhone application, you need Mac OS X computer running the Xcode tool and developer having sound knowledge of Objective C. Xcode is Apple’s suite of development toos that provide support for project management, source level debugging, code editing, code building, performance tuning etc.

**Xcode** : Xcode is an integrated development environment (IDE) that provides all of the tools you need to create and manage your iPhone projects and source files, build your code into an executable, and run and debug your code either in iPhone simulator or on a device.

**Instruments**: Instrument will require ensuring that you delivering the best user experience and lets you analyze the performance of your iphone application while running on device. Instrument will help you to gathers data from your running application and present that data in a graphical display called timeline.

**Interface Builder**: Interface Builder is the tool you use to assemble your application’s user interface visually. Using Interface Builder, you assemble your application’s window by dragging and dropping pre-configured components onto it.

([Ref](http://www.eltalearning.com/iphone-application-development-tools-and-requirement/2009/02/23/)).

Comment: when i tried to install the Xcode it's ask me the upgrade of OSX... but i want to creata app only for this old devices...

Comment: @Antonio You need an older Xcode version compatible with this Mac OS X version, find more information here: http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/200099-installing-xcode.html Fortunately or not, the Xcode might be legally downloaded only with the Apple developer account. As an alternative, some compatible Xcode version must be on your Mac OS X installation CD if you still have it. The official sample applications might be found here https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action There a lot of open-source apps to play with on github.com

Comment: where i find the version of xcode i need?

Comment: you can find them on iTunes just type Xcode and it will take you to the latest version of it that page also contains one link which will take you to the older version of it

Comment: sorry not on iTunes just see my answer for this

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the link but you need one appleid to download it the link is [this](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)

and you can get one id free at [here](https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/register.woa/wa/default?userAction=createAccount&mode=register&successURL=https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/login.action&cancelURL=https://developer.apple.com/programs)